# How to extend selection to string without quotes?

Tags: intellij-idea

I remember being able to extend selection (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) within a string to select the text, but without quotes or apostrophes. Right now if I try it, it will select the word first and then the entire string INCLUDING quotes. Is there any setting or plugin that will allow me to extend selection to string without quotes first and then if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> again, it will include quotes?

I currently have default settings and no plugins.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me on macOS. Could you share a code sample and information from `Help | About` to better understand your environment? Ensure that `Ctrl+W` is properly assigned to `Extend Selection` under `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`

Comment: Can you give an example piece of code where extending the selection works like this? Also, what version of IntelliJ are you running? For me it seems to be working fine on linux with IntelliJ 2023.2 EAP.